# How to optimize a SQL query with In

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I optimize a SQL query like the one below?

```
SELECT COUNT(R.RiskID) AS RiskCount 
FROM   Rpt_Risk R JOIN Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA  
ON     R.RiskID = IMA.FKRiskID
WHERE  IMA.FKItemID = 38
AND    IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%'
AND    IMA.FKPLanID NOT IN 
                      (
                       SELECT IA.FKPlanID 
                       FROM Rpt_ImpactAssessment IA JOIN RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP  
                       ON IA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID  
                       JOIN RM_Action A    
                       ON LAP.ActionID = A.ActionID 
                       AND IA.FKItemID = 38
                       AND IA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%'
                      )
```

Comment: At the least, tell us what you've tried; show us an execution plan; show some table definitions.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't optimal already?

Comment: I'm assuming you have all the right indexes..?

Comment: It is difficult to guess what is possible to optimize in the query while we don't know query execution plan. It will be fine if you provide DDL script to create tables and all indexes on the tables.

Comment: Query which which I tries and came up is like above which is returning Risk count but as you can see I am using Rpt_ImpactAssessment table twise. How can we replace NOT IN or IN clause with join :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `risk` table doesn't seem to be used, assuming that the `RiskID`s match in both tables (so the `join` is not doing any filtering).

Second, you seem to asking "which 38/High plans have no match in the LinkActionToPlan table".  If I have this right, you can further simply the query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RiskCount 
FROM Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA  
WHERE IMA.FKItemID = 38 AND
      IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%' AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP  join
                       RM_Action A
                       on LAP.ActionID = A.ActionID
                  where IMA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID
                 );
```

There is no filtering on `RM_Action`, so I suspect that this table could also be removed from the query.

Comment: We can have a case in which RiskID dose not exits in Rpt_ImpactAssessment table then, about other things I am agree with you.

Comment: Sorry my mistake you are right, As Risk is associated with itemid in Rpt_ImpactAssessment. So every every riskID should be there.

Comment: how can return in one select query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS RiskCount FROM Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA WHERE IMA.FKItemID = 38 AND
      IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%' AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP       
                  where IMA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID
                 )
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RiskCount FROM Rpt_ImpactAssessment IMA  
WHERE IMA.FKItemID = 38 AND IMA.ImpactCurPIDLevel LIKE '%High%' AND
       EXISTS (select 1
                  from RM_LinkActionToPlan LAP       
                  where IMA.FKPlanID = LAP.PlanID
                 )

Comment: @user3271821 . . . If you have another question, you should ask it as a separate question and not in a comment.  You can refer back to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the analyzer (how it works depends on your type of server).
If the `IN` query runs ONLY once, nothing to optimize in terms of the query.
If, it runs for every record found in the main query, u r in trouble...In such case:

1. If the inner query results are fetched from query cach, no big deal.
2. If the inner query results are are only a couple of hundred ids, u can fetch them in a separate query, and just hard code the argument.
3. If there are too many ids to hard code into the main query, One option would be to create a temp table with ALL the ids u want, and simply `JOIN` it with the main query.

Really depends on how your app is written to come up with more optimization ideas.